# Stalonetray suddenly appears on wrong monitor

Tags: xmonad

I have had some (limited) success using stalonetray to show simple tray icons for apps like Discord/Teams

Today, all of a sudden I noticed that stalonetray started appearing on my secondary monitor for some reason

I need it to appear on my primary, as that is where my xmobar appears

I tried killing it and then re-opening it but I keep getting these error messages which I am unable to decipher:

```
$ stalonetray -display HDMI-1-1
```

> could not open display

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Same occurs when trying e.g. `-display 1`

IMO the docs on this are absolutely terrible, as I have no idea what is meant by the help text, i.e.

```
use X display <display>
```

Am I just missing something here, or how could I possibly have caused it to suddenly start appearing on the wrong monitor?

---

I tried restarting xmonad, but every time it appears on the wrong monitor

the only way to get it to work is to completely sign out of xmonad and log back in, and about 50% of the time, it appears on the correct monitor

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried `-display :0`?

Comment: @mashuptwice I don't remember if I ever  did, I but I have since switched to `trayer` as it gives me less problems